# Unity3D - Variable Unassigned even though assigned in Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As shown below, The Unity compiler threw this exception for the code highlighted on line 27:

`UnassignedReferenceException:` `The variable HighwayPrefab of TileScript has not been assigned`

Even though I assigned the prefab in the Inspector (Highlighted).

[image: Error]

The above `TileScript` is called from the code below:
[image: Start]

The meta file of `TileScript` shows that I assigned the prefab:

[image: meta]

Comment: Did you stop the running project, then assign and save everything before running again? Just asking cause it has caused me couple of headaches.

Comment: Yes, I assigned the prefab before I run the scene

Comment: If you're dealing with Unity's networking.  A huge gotchya is, that script ***MAY BE ON ANOTHER OBJECT***, where you didn't think to assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a empty GameObject and add TileScript to it. Then assign your prefabs to your script.

Comment: `TileScript` is already the component of `TilePrefab` as shown in `start()`, `TilePrefab` get instantiated when I run the scene

Comment: can you show how did you assign prefabs to TilePrefab?

Comment: I solved the error, thanks. so I assigned the variables in the script inspector. But apparently I need to assign them to the script component of The TilePrefab too.

Comment: @Ja.L Yes, of course. Because you're instantiating the prefab (copying it). If a value isn't assigned in the original, then it won't be assigned in the copy either.